# ¿Cómo regresar al inicio de la comparación?

Tags: python

Necesito que el programa me regrese si pongo algo incorrecto, pero aunque lo ponga correcto me regresa. Este es el código que tengo:

```
while True:
    Rodaje1 = input(":")
    time.sleep(1)
    if "inicia rodaje a la pista 1" in Rodaje1:

                print("(RoyalAir) ok iniciando rodaje")
                winsound.PlaySound("Prop_Plane_Start", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
                time.sleep(10)
                print("(RoyalAir) Royal1345 a ATC solicito permiso de despege ")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("Quiere despegar, solo di (solicitud aceptada)")

                while True:
                      despege1 = input(":")
                      if "solicitud aceptada" in despege1:

                          time.sleep(1)
                          print("(RoyalAir) Ok despege!!")
                          winsound.PlaySound("Bahamasair Takeoff with Prop Effect  Dash 8-300", winsound.SND_ASYNC)

                      else:
                          print("No entiendo")
    else:
         print("No entiendo")
```

Comment: Hola! Tienes 2 `while True: ` y en ninguno cambias la condición a `False` por lo que no saldrás nunca de ellos. Cuando se deba salir de los bucles, cambia a False para terminar la iteración.

Comment: Como dice @Borjinha10, el `while` repetirá mientras la condición que le pongas sea `True`. Ya que no le pones una variable que pueda cambiar a `False`, repetirá por siempre. Pero si dentro del bucle hay un `break`, entonces saldrías. Puede ser una alternativa en tu caso. Cuando detectes una entrada válida, sales con `break`